# Looking at the Diophantine equation $x^2 - 31y^2 = -1$, I know that it is not solvable but am not sure how to prove why it isn't solvable.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I looked at the period of the continued fraction expansion of the $\sqrt{31}$. I noticed that it has an even period $(8)$ which indicates that it isn't solvable for $-1$. I'm not sure how to go about proving that an even period means the equation is not solvable.

Comment: Continued fractions are unnecessary. Look at both sides mod $31$: it becomes $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod 31$. Since $31 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, $-1$ is not a square modulo $31$. This is the same reasoning as that used to show $x^2 - 3y^2 = -1$ has no integral solution.

Comment: This paper : http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Papers1/42-2/quartrippon02_2004.pdf may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo $4$ we have $x^2\equiv 0$ or $x^2 \equiv 1.$ Also $-31 y^2\equiv 32y^2-31 y^2=y^2,$ and $y^2\equiv 0$ or $y^2\equiv 1 .$  So $x^2+y^2$ cannot be congruent to $-1$ modulo $4.$